# Data driven scenario for Robot Framework

Tags: nested-loops, robotframework

I want to have username and pwd set in variable file and as the test steps through each username, it advances to the next row of data.

I am using resource files to drive the data, and my initial FOR script processes username 1 (eeny), then the nested FOR loop passes all of the passwords at once.

```
*** Variables  ***
@{users}  eeny  meeny  miny  moe
@{pwds}  pwd  pwd1  pwd2  pwd3

*** Test Cases ***

Login Test
    :FOR    ${u}    IN    @{users}
    \   Open Browser  ${URL}
    \   set window size  1440  900
    \   set selenium speed  .5
    \   input text  id=username  ${u}
    \   :FOR  ${p}  IN  @{pwds}
    \   \  input text  id=password  ${p}
    \   \  click button  css=button.primary
    \   \  wait until page contains  css=p.logout
    \   \  capture page screenshot
    \   \  click element  css=p.logout
```

Currently I am trying for a nested FOR statement, or a FOR statement that declares both username and password variables in the same time, but am not opposed to changing tactics for getting the data and using a multi dimensional array or similar if that worked better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Driven testing can be achieved through 'Data Driven through Test Template' or Read data from Excel or csv.

'Data Driven through Test Template' 
  In this we will create a user defined keyword which is nothing but the function or source code which we want to execute for multiple times.
that we declare as `'Test Template'` in `Settings` section. 
when we give the TestCase name with arguments , it will execute `Test Template` each time.
    
 here the sample code

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     This Test Suite Deals with Data Driven Testing using Test Template Method
Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
Test Template     Validate Login with Differnt Valid Credentials

*** Variables ***
${URL}            http://ururl
${Browser}        chrome
${Title}          HomePage
${delay}          5s

*** Test Cases ***    USERNAME    PASSWORD
Test User             user1       user1

Admin User            admin       admin

*** Keywords ***
Validate Login with Differnt Valid Credentials
    [Arguments]    ${Uname}    ${Pwd}
    Open the Browser and enter the URL    ${URL}    ${Browser}
    Enter the User Name    ${Uname}
    Enter the Password    ${Pwd}
    Click on Submit button
    Verify HomePage displayed    ${Title}

Open the Browser and enter the URL
    [Arguments]    ${URL}    ${Browser}
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${Browser}

Enter the User Name
    [Arguments]    ${UserName}
    Sleep    ${delay}
    Input Text    id=username    ${UserName}

Enter the Password
    [Arguments]    ${Password}
    Input Text    id=password    ${Password}

Click on Submit button
    Click Button    css=.btn.btn-primary

Verify HomePage displayed
    [Arguments]    ${Title}
    Sleep    ${delay}
    Title Should Be    ${Title}
```

'Data driven by read from Excel'

 Read the values from Excel sheet and run multiple times,
    
 here the sample code

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     CLM Registration Test Case
Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           Collections
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           String

*** Variables ***
${delay}          2s
${excelName}      LoginTestData.xls
${rowCount}       ${EMPTY}
${cellCount}      ${EMPTY}
${URL}            http://Ur test Test URL
${Browser}        chrome

*** Test Cases ***
ReadFromExcelSheet
    Open Excel Sheet    ${excelName}
    @{sheetNames}    Get Sheet Names
    ${sheetName}    Set Variable    @{sheetNames}[0]
    ${rowCount}    Get Row Count    ${sheetName}
    ${cellCount}    Get Column Count    ${sheetName}
    #for loop to read all the rows in excel
    : FOR    ${rindex}    IN RANGE    1    ${rowCount}
    \    @{rowValues}    Create List
    \    @{rowValues}    Get Values    ${sheetName}    ${rindex}    ${cellCount}
    \    Log to console    row values are for index ${rindex} : @{rowValues}
    \    Sleep    ${delay}
    \    Open Browser    ${url} ${Browser}
    \    Enter User Name    @{rowValues}[0]
    \    Enter Password     @{rowValues}[1]
    \    Click on Submit Button

*** Keywords ***
Open Excel Sheet
    [Arguments]    ${excelName}
    Open Excel    ${excelName}    useTempDir=False

Get Values
    [Arguments]    ${sName}    ${row}    ${cCount}
    Log to console    user is in Get Values function
    @{rValues}    Create List
    : FOR    ${cindex}    IN RANGE    0    ${cCount}
    \    Log to console    get the data from ${sName}[${cindex}][${row}]
    \    ${cellValue}    Read Cell Data By Coordinates    ${sName}    ${cindex}    ${row}
    \    Insert Into List    ${rValues}    ${cindex}    ${cellValue}
    [Return]    @{rValues}


Open The Browser
       [Arguments]    ${url}    ${Browser}
       Open Browser   ${url}    ${Browser}

Enter User Name    
       [Arguments]    username
       Input Text    id=username    username


Enter Password     
       [Arguments]   password
       Input Password    id=password    password

Click on Submit Button
       Click Button    css=.btn.btn-primary
```

Comment: why have you mentioned excel?

Comment: as we can read data from excel and do data driven testing, i have mentioned excel

Comment: we can but the person asking the question clearly shows no need for this?  It certainly can be valuable in certain instances but I'd be careful not to confuse those you're trying to help

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your assistance - I was able to take bits from each offering and migrate them to one script that works!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a misunderstanding between a single test case and multiple.  What you have above will input a username, then it will cycle through one password, submit and logout.  Only if you happen to have the same element on the next page will it attempt to input another password.

I suggest having a look here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style

Also have a look at a number of similar questions, you need to provide a test template, worry about looping later when you have it working for two test cases would be my suggestion.